# C# 7zip compress but not open

Tags: c#, 7zip, sevenzipsharp

I used SevenZipSharp for compress my folders
I have some code in c#

```
SevenZipExtractor.SetLibraryPath(@"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.dll");//x64    
var cmpr = new SevenZipCompressor();
cmpr.CompressionFinished += (s, e) => { dof.DoFinishEvent(); cmpr = null; };
cmpr.BeginCompressDirectory("C:\\58", "C:\\58.7z");
```

It's working, but archive which created has some lock[image]

Please, help me to fix it! Thanks!

Comment: Looks like the archive file is being flagged as 'read only'.  I'm not sure how to tell the 7zip library not to do this, but you could try clearing the flag yourself: `new FileInfo("C:\\58.7z").IsReadOnly = false`

Comment: don't work on drive C , windows put special security for drive C, try D (if any) and tell us.

Comment: No. This not work (IsRead and drive D)